# How to show error message in different languages

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am developing an APP where user wants to show the error message in different languages. For example In Sign up page if the user enters the email ID which is already registered it will show the error as "Email ID already registered". I am getting this error message from API. All error message is having different codes. My doubt is how to translate the error message with code which is coming from API. As of now I am using the below code where I will directly give the Error message. Any one can help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

```
export function SignUp(props: any) {
  const { 
    signupData, isRegd, dispatch,
  } = props; 
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [fname, setFName] = useState('');
  const [lname, setLName] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [result, setResult] = useState(SignUp.result);
  const [signupvalidated, setSignupValidated] = useState(false);
   const settingResult = () => {
    setResult(SignUp.result);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setResult(null);
      dispatch(resetsignup());
    }, 2000);
  };
  const signupHandler = (event: any) => {
    const form = event.currentTarget;
    const obj: any = serialize(form, { hash: true });
    if (form.checkValidity()) {
      dispatch(userRegistration(obj)).then((isSuccess: any) => {
        if (isSuccess) {
          settingResult();
        }
      });
      event.preventDefault(); 
      event.stopPropagation(); 
    } else {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
    setSignupValidated(true);
  };
  return (
    <div className="signupFormData">
      <h5 className={`${styles.mt30} ${styles.mb30} ${'text-center'}`}>{t('SignUpmodal.lblSgnmyFYONE')}</h5>
      <Form id="signupForm" noValidate validated={signupvalidated} onSubmit={(ev: any) => signupHandler(ev)}>
        {
          (!isRegd && typeof result !== 'undefined' && result)
            ? map(result.msgs, (erList: any) => (
              <Alert key={erList.code} variant="danger">{erList.msgText}</Alert>
            ))
            : ''
        }
        {
          (isRegd && result)
            ? (
              <Alert key={isRegd} variant="success">
                {t('Loginmodal.lblPrflRegstrSucs')}
                !!!
              </Alert>
            )
            : ''
        }
        <div className={`${styles.formClm2} ${styles.labelInline}`}>
          <Form.Group>
            <div className={styles.inlineGroup}>
              <Form.Control required type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value={fname} onChange={(value: any) => { setFName(value.target.value); nameHandler(value); }} className={`${styles.formControl} ${fname.length > 0 ? styles.hasContent : ''}`} />
            </div>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group>
            <div className={styles.inlineGroup}>
              <Form.Control required type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value={lname} onChange={(value: any) => { setLName(value.target.value); nameHandler(value); }} className={`${styles.formControl} ${lname.length > 0 ? styles.hasContent : ''}`} />
            </div>
          </Form.Group>
        </div>
          <Form.Group>
            <div className={styles.inlineGroup}>
              <Form.Control required autoComplete="new-emailAddress" type="email" name="emailAddress" value={email} onChange={(value: any) => { setEmail(value.target.value); }} className={`${styles.formControl} ${email.length > 0 ? styles.hasContent : ''}`} />
              <Form.Label>{t('SignUp.lblEmailID')}</Form.Label>
            </div>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group>
            <div className={styles.inlineGroup}>
              <Form.Control required type="password" name="profileInfo[password]" value={password} onChange={(value: any) => { setPassword(value.target.value); }} className={`${styles.formControl} ${password.length > 0 ? styles.hasContent : ''}`} />
              <Form.Label>{t('SignUp.lblPassword')}</Form.Label>
            </div>
          </Form.Group>
        <div className={styles.tabFooter}>
          <Button type="submit" className={`${styles.btn} ${styles.btnContinue}`}>{t('SignUp.lblSgnUp')}</Button>
        </div>
        </div>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}



//Language Change Code translation.json file:

 "ErrorMsg": {
        "60" : "Email address already exists"
    }

  }

   "ErrorMsg": {
        "60" : " Această adresă de e-mail a fost deja înregistrată."
    }

  }
```

Comment: I think you can show a dropdown on top showing the languages and based on the selection you can show the error like state{ language : 'en' } then on error msg you can check this.state.language and accordingly show the error. Or else you need to go to the route of a particular language and then show the error ( https://medium.com/prototyped/multi-language-routing-in-react-d7eb7a0688e9 )

Answer (score 0):

you can implement a solution using [react native localization](https://github.com/stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization) it will work perfectly with your case if you think there is something not clear ask.